# How do VLSMs work?

Tags: subnet, network

I recently came across a question which I don't know is a genuine one and the question was,

Which of the following options are examples of VLSM?

- A. Subnetting 192.168.1.0/27 into multiple /30s
- B. Subnetting 192.168.1.0/24 into multiple /29s
- C. Subnetting 172.16.1.0/24 into multiple /26s
- D. Subnetting 10.1.24.128/26 into multiple /28s
- E. Subnetting 172.16.0.0/16 into multiple /24s

And the correct options were A, C & D.

I fail to understand this question though I know what VLSMs are and how they work. Because, I can subnet a 192.168.1.0/24 into multiple /29s, right?!

Can someone explain what's been asked and how to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Obsolete questions like this are one of the reasons all "_education, certification, or homework_" questions are explicitly off-topic here. This question really has nothing to do with professional business networks because classful networking has been dead for over 20 years, and is not used in modern networking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the Class of the IP Address, the ones you have identified as being the correct answers are already subnetted and are then going to be split again.

Comment: @shudershan Keep in mind that classful addressing is an obsolete concept, and has been since before you were born.  VLSM is a holdover from that time.  Let it die in peace.

Comment: @Ron Trunk I thought about classfull addressing, obviously, while trying to come up with a solution, but was confused by the fact that "Subnetting 192.168.1.0/24 into multiple /29s" has /29 which is classless.

Comment: @Sudershan VLSM was a hack to "fix" classfull addressing.  Both concepts are obsolete.

Comment: @RonTrunk Now that, i will keep in my mind. Hah